# How do I play YouTube videos with iOS-GTLYouTube library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, playback

I'm trying to play YouTube videos using the iOS-GTLYouTube library. I just finished the query code for my videos and got back a few GTLYouTubeVideo objects. So after I got them, then what? How do I play it? I've searched the web but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't play videos with the GTLYouTube library, you can only use it to search the API for video information.

After retrieving the Video ID of the video you want to play, you can load that id into the iFrame up in a UIWebView.

```
NSString *videoID = @"HCdUubr70i8"; // the video ID returned from your API query

// Adjust the width and height to your liking, I just pass in the view's frame width and height
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%@' height='%@' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height, videoID];


UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView ...];
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Google also provides their own UIWebView wrapper class, [youtube-ios-player-helper](http://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), which makes YouTube video playback on iOS devices a little easier.